# How to provide translations for a WordPress TinyMCE plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, javascript, tinymce, translation, localization

I know that I can get my translations into JavaScript doing:

```
    $MyTranslations = array(
        'translation1' => __("Some String 1", "MyTranslations"),
        'translation2' => __("Some String 2", "MyTranslations")
    );
    wp_localize_script( 'jquery', 'my_translations', $MyTranslations );
```

But looking at some of WordPress TinyMCE plugins they use calls like this:

```
{
title : ed.getLang('advlink.link_desc'),
...
}
```

How is WordPress getting their translations into `getLang()`? Am I supposed to do it this way or do I just use my first bit of code and access the variables directly like:

```
{
title : my_translations.translation1,
...
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the filter `'mce_external_languages'`. From `wp-includes/class-wp-editor.php`:

> The following filter loads external language files for TinyMCE plugins.
>       It takes an associative array 'plugin_name' => 'path', where path is the
>       include path to the file. The language file should follow the same format as
>       `/tinymce/langs/wp-langs.php` and should define a variable $strings that
>       holds all translated strings.
>       When this filter is not used, the function will try to load `{mce_locale}.js`.
>       If that is not found, en.js will be tried next.

```
$mce_external_languages = apply_filters('mce_external_languages', array());
```

I would just use a copy of `wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/wp-langs.php` … and drop that superfluous `mce_escape()` in favour of the original `esc_js()`.

### Sample file:

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

$strings = 'tinyMCE.addI18n(
    {' . _WP_Editors::$mce_locale . '.extrastrings:
        {
            helloworld: "' . esc_js( __( 'Hello World', 'my_plugin_text_domain' ) ) . '",
            foobar: "' . esc_js( __( 'Foo Bar', 'my_plugin_text_domain' ) ) . '"
        }
    }
)';
```

In your plugin you just use:

```
add_filter( 'mce_external_languages', 'wpse_44785_add_tinymce_lang', 10, 1 );

function wpse_44785_add_tinymce_lang( $arr )
{
    $arr[] = 'full_path_to_lang_file.php';
    return $arr;
}
```

To access the new strings in JavaScript use for example:

```
title : ed.getLang('extrastrings.helloworld')
```

Comment: I'm trying to follow your answer, and I don't understand how to actually call the strings, after adding my local php file... Could you help please?

Comment: @LeaCohen Not sure what you mean with _call_. The `ed.getLang()` part?

Comment: Yes, than k you for understanding.. What parameter do I pass to `ed.getLang()` when I build my php file like your sample file?

Comment: @LeaCohen `ed.getLang('extrastrings.helloworld')` – do you mean that? :)

Comment: Yes, thank you, that's what I meant! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample file gaved me an error (undefined . before **extrastrings**).
So i changed code:

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

$strings = 'tinyMCE.addI18n( "' . _WP_Editors::$mce_locale . '.extrastrings", {
    title: "' . esc_js( __( 'Shortcodes', 'm7' ) ) . '",
    popup_title: "' . esc_js( __( 'Шорткоды', 'm7' ) ) . '"
} )';
```

Comment: This looks like it should be a suggested edit to an existing answer rather than a new answer?

Comment: Yes it is, i'm a n00be here and a Russian ( >D ), so forgive me, haven't seen that there's a way to add comment before you wrote :(

Comment: With 1 rep you couldn't add a comment, but I think (I am not 100% sure) that you can always suggest an edit to either the question or an answer. The edit won't post without approval by higher ranked users though.