# Localize variables with TinyMCE script

Tags: tinymce, wp-localize-script

I am writing a plugin that has variables that I would like to localize for use within TinyMCE. The logical choice seemed to me to localise them with the enqueued TinyMCE script itself like so:

```
public function localize_variables() {
    wp_localize_script( 'tinymce', 'varName', 'value' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'localize_variables' );
```

However I can't find where TinyMCE is being enqueued!

I put this little function at the bottom of my functions page and ran it on my Admin edit posts page:

```
function my_inspect_scripts() {
    global $wp_scripts;
    print_r($wp_scripts);
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'my_inspect_scripts' );
```

After going through the data dump I noticed that TinyMCE was not in the list of scripts being enqueued! However the script its self was being loaded as a resource within the browser.

I feel like I am missing something here.

Comment: Probably related: [How to provide translations for a WordPress TinyMCE plugin?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44785/how-to-provide-translations-for-a-wordpress-tinymce-plugin)

Comment: [The script slug is `tiny_mce` not `tinymce`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script). You have the handle wrong.

Comment: There is no tiny_mce either... Is it possibly no longer loaded through the enqueue process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks as though Tiny MCE is not enqueued. Looks like it is loaded through the _WP_Editors class in class-wp-editor.php.

There is a action hook in there called `before_wp_tiny_mce` where you can output a script with some localised variables... This is what I am going to do.